# Gzip not working, server 2012, IIS 8

Tags: iis, server, compression, gzip, iis-8

Problems with activating Gzip on IIS 8 on a windows server 2012 (standard)

- So i activated the compressions in the windows features
- I checked both checkboxes in IIS - compression (dynamic and static)

But still no Gzip available.
However, on my localhost machine (just a windows 10) this works.

What i do see, is that the gzip temp directory (C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files) is getting filled up when i browse my site via the server localhost. BUT strangely enough i'm not seeing anything Gzip-ped in chrome.

The only headers (in chrome) are:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0a354779de8d11:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2016 13:41:04 GMT

(Even yslow is saying no gzip is activated)

When i remove the gzip temp folder, and browse to the site trough the 'official'  website url, then nothing is even generated.

Does anyone has any idea what is going on here?

//edit:
Even added this in the web.config

```
<httpCompression> 
  <staticTypes> 
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" /> 
  </staticTypes> 
  <dynamicTypes> 
    <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" /> 
    <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" /> 
  </dynamicTypes> 
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" dynamicCompressionLevel="4" /> 
</httpCompression>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would troubleshoot this:

I'm using PowerShell here, but you could use the GUI or other tools as well:

Make sure you have the failed request tracing module installed:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpTracing
```

enable the tracing for your site (change the name):

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']/traceFailedRequestsLogging" -name "enabled" -value "True"
```

Setup tracing:

```
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests" -name "." -value @{path='*.html'}
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*.html']/traceAreas" -name "." -value @{provider='WWW Server';areas='Compression';verbosity='Verbose'}
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site'  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*.html']/failureDefinitions" -name "statusCodes" -value "200,304"
```

you end up with something like this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <tracing>
        <traceFailedRequests>
            <add path="*.html">
                <traceAreas>
                    <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Compression" verbosity="Verbose" />
                </traceAreas>
                <failureDefinitions statusCodes="200,304" />
            </add>
        </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
</system.webServer>
```

I limited it to html files with a http status of 200 or 304 and we are only interested in `Compression`. You may want to change that.

Now you can hit your site a few times and then look in

```
C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVCx
```

for some files, copy them to your workstation, because it's a pain to open them on the server.

Open the XML files and click on the `Request Details` tab, now search for `Compression` you should see details about the compression process or a reason why the request wasn't compress, like `NOT_FREQUENTLY_HIT` or `TOO SMALL`