# Gzip not working - NO_MATCHING_SCHEME

Tags: iis, server, compression, gzip, iis-8

Problems with activating Gzip on IIS 8 on a windows server 2012 (standard)

- So i activated the compressions in the windows features
- I checked both checkboxes in IIS - compression (dynamic and static)
  But still no Gzip available. However, on my localhost machine (just a windows 10) this works.

What i do see, is that the gzip temp directory (C:\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files) is getting filled up when i browse my site via the server localhost. BUT strangely enough i'm not seeing anything Gzip-ped in chrome.

The only headers (in chrome) are: HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified Accept-Ranges: bytes ETag: "0a354779de8d11:0" Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Thu, 28 Jul 2016 13:41:04 GMT

(Even yslow is saying no gzip is activated)

When i remove the gzip temp folder, and browse to the site trough the 'official' website url, then nothing is even generated.

Does anyone has any idea what is going on here?

I added this in my web.config

```
<httpCompression> 
 <staticTypes> 
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" /> 
 </staticTypes> 
 <dynamicTypes> 
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" /> 
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" /> 
 </dynamicTypes> 
 <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" dynamicCompressionLevel="4" /> 
</httpCompression>
```

See this other topic, where i activated more log information, [Gzip not working, server 2012, IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38638490/gzip-not-working-server-2012-iis-8)

All i get is:

```
<RenderingInfo Culture="nl-BE">
 <Opcode>STATIC_COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS</Opcode>
 <Keywords>
  <Keyword>Compression</Keyword>
 </Keywords>
 <freb:Description Data="Reason">NO_MATCHING_SCHEME</freb:Description>
</RenderingInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding this to your web.config file ?? I suggest so because it worked for me on IIS windows shared hosting. Its similar to your code with a few changes...

```
<system.webServer>
      <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
        <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
        <dynamicTypes>  
          <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
        </dynamicTypes>
        <staticTypes>
          <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="application/javascript; charset=utf-8" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
          <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
        </staticTypes>

  </httpCompression>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm not sure if you need to add

```
<add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" />
```

Isn't jpeg a compressed format ? You could add it none the less if you wish to.

[OPTIONAL]: I read this at [MaxCdn](https://www.maxcdn.com/blog/accept-encoding-its-vary-important/).

Origin servers should include Vary: Accept-Encoding, and here’s how:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
    <remove name="Vary"></remove>
    <add name="Vary" value="Accept-Encoding"></add>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

You can add this bit to your web.config file as well, deploy and check it in the request headers through your browser's developer tools itself.